# UIImagePicker transition to modalViewController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller

After selecting an image from the UIImagePicker, I'd like to transition (crossFade) to a modal viewController that is presented behind the imagePicker.

The problem I'm having is animating a transition from one modal (UIImagePicker) window to another modal window. If I dismiss the imagePicker and present the new modal they both disappear. If there is a delay between the dismissing the imagePicker and presenting of the new modal, it functionally works, but it doesn't provide a smooth transition.

How can I accomplish a smooth transition from one modal to the next?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no direct method. Work around I think is like this:
You can present the UIImagePickerController from your TargetViewController(that you want to present after dismissing be UIImagePickerController) with one of its view hidden (Image View). In the UIImagePickerController delegate, you can set the required image and make it visible in the TargetViewController. After dismissing the UIImagePickerController, you will get the required transition.